# Unload event in Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm using PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile to develop an Android app.

I'm trying to bind a function call to the event of the user leaving the page (back button or clicking some other link).

What I have so far:

```
        $(window).unload(function () {
            //my function
        })
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the pagebeforehide of jQuery Mobile . From jQuery Mobile documentation:

**pagebeforehide**  event:

Triggered on the "fromPage" we are transitioning away from, before the actual transition animation is kicked off. Callbacks for this event will receive a data object as their 2nd arg. This data object has the following properties on it:
nextPage (object)
A jQuery collection object that contains the page DOM element that we are transitioning to.
Note that this event will not be dispatched during the transition of the first page at application startup since there is no previously active page.